# Where to find this specific source (centos 2.6.18-53.el5PAE)

Tags: linux, kernel, centos, source

okay all my looking around on the normal kernel site ftp can't find it. I need specifically, the PAE version. I am compiling virtualbox and if you don't use the right source you get this lovely:
vboxdrv: disagrees about version of symbol struct_module

Comment: There's no such thing as a PAE version of the kernel *source*. Judging by your [earlier question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17287), you need to compile the kernel with the right configuration (`.config`).

Comment: I did get the kernel to compile, but i'm getting this error: vboxnetflt: Unknown symbol consume_skb  which is suggesting the wrong kernel version. I can't upgrade, so how do i make them match?

Comment: 2.6.18 is pretty old (yeah, I know, CentOS). Do recent versions of VirtualBox still support such old versions? The kernel source has been reorganized quite a bit since then, so it would be understandable if they'd dropped compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't need the "real" kernel sources for CentOS - see [this wiki page](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source).

Anyway, any kernel source *should* be in the `.src` RPM which for older versions of CentOS can be found at http://vault.centos.org/

Comment: http://vault.centos.org/5.1/os/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.18-53.el5.src.rpm is the specific SRPM, it will build the PAE kernel from the SRPM